# Angular not showing json data on screen - Angular 1.6.9

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, angularjs, json

I have a php file and it works to parse the data from mysql in a json format
this is the result I get,

```
"{\"records\":[{\"EmpName\":\"Justin\",\"EmpAddress\":\"New York\",
\"emp_email\":\"justin@yahoo.com\"},{\"EmpName\":\"Mark\",\"EmpAddress
\":\"Canada\",\"emp_email\":\"Mark@gmail.com\"},{\"EmpName\":\"Sachin
\",\"EmpAddress\":\"India\",\"emp_email\":\"sachin05@gmail.com
\"},{\"EmpName\":\"Rachel\",\"EmpAddress\":\"Australia\",\"emp_email
\":\"rachel1221@outlook.com\"},{\"EmpName\":\"John\",\"EmpAddress
\":\"Russia\",\"emp_email\":\"john55@yahoo.com\"}]}"
```

This is my angular code

```
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

        <?php $url = '"' . $url . '/customers_mysql.php"';
        ?>
    console.log(<?php echo $url; ?>);
        $http.get(<?php echo $url; ?>)  
        .then(function(response) {
        console.log("test");
        console.log(response.data); 
        $scope.names = response.data.records;

    });

});
```

This is my controller in my html file

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl">

<table>
  <tr ng-repeat="x in names">
    <td>{{x.EmpName}}</td>
    <td>{{x.EmpAddress}}</td>
      <td>{{x.emp_email}}</td> 
  </tr>
</table>

</div>
```

I dont see any data appear on the screen or any error message appear in Console. I see the json shows the data ok by using the console.log(response.data); It shows up in the console but angular is not showing up the data on the page?
Any idea why it's not parsing the data? Is it because of the records in front of json? I tried to remove also the "records:" in front of json but then it's also not showing up.

**EDIT:** 
This is in my php file to parse data from array in to json

```
$outp = "";
while($rs = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    if ($outp != "") {$outp .= ",";}
    $outp .= '{"EmpName":"'  . $rs["EmpName"] . '",';
    $outp .= '"EmpAddress":"'   . $rs["EmpAddress"]        . '",';
    $outp .= '"emp_email":"'. $rs["emp_email"]     . '"}';
}
$outp ='{"records":['.$outp.']}';
$mysqli->close();




echo json_encode($outp);
```

Comment: Does the actual php output have the outer wrapping quotes as shown? If so it shouldn't and how they get added is suspicous

Comment: Is your response.data interpreted as json? If Can you post a screenshot of the console.log(response.data) somewhere? I think your string might not parse as json and instead be interpretted as a string

Comment: this is my response data in console
http://oi66.tinypic.com/zjb7fd.jpg

Comment: Don't manually create JSON .... it is a lot of extra work and error prone. Create a php  array with the data and once it is created use `echo json_encode($data);`.  See [json_encode() docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

Comment: @charlietfl added part of my php code that I have to fetch the array from database, I have the json encode at end

Comment: also set to json as follows in php file
header('Content-Type: application/json');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are double encoding the json. json_encode does the encoding for you, you just need to fill an array. Try something like

```
$outp = [];
while($rs = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $outp [] = ["EmpName"=>$rs["EmpName"],
                "EmpAddress" => $rs["EmpAddress"],
                "emp_email" => $rs["emp_email"]];
}

$mysqli->close();
echo json_encode(["records" => $outp]);
```

Comment: Thanks! Like this it works :-)
So it's always best to store first in php array and after words encode.Intersting to know!

Comment: @TomJacobs Happy it helped

Answer (score 0):

You are creating json string yourself in php when you should be just creating an array. Then you json_encode the array not the string

Try changing to:

```
$outp = array("records" => array());

while ($rs = $result - > fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

  $outp["records"][] = array(
    "EmpName" => $rs["EmpName"],
    "EmpAddress" => $rs["EmpAddress"],
    "emp_email" => $rs["emp_email"]
  );
}

$mysqli - > close();

echo json_encode($outp);
```

Comment: Thanks, seems similar to Jakub Judas answer. It works with above solution. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Right...but was my efforts and questioning that got down to the actual problem that wasn't apparent in original code that was shown. Keep that in mind

Comment: will this code work perfectly fine in Angular 2? Or is there anything that will have to be changed?

Comment: How you send json from back end has nothing to do with whatever framework you use in front end